# What is the latest support library

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-support-library

I am using this in gradle:
com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0

But AS tells me it is not matching with my compile version of 23? What lib version do I have to use?

Comment: whats the log? or error message?

Comment: the support library (22) should not use a different version of the compiledsdk version (23)

Comment: The major version of the support libraries (22 for `com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0`) should match your `compileSdkVersion`. And, for any current development work, your `compileSdkVersion` usually should be the latest (at the moment, 25).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `gradle: com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0` or `gradle: com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0`

but I recommend download latest SDK(26) then use `gradle: com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0`